# Testing for Exceptions using JUnit. Test fails even if the Exception is caught

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit

I am new to testing with JUnit and I need a hint on testing Exceptions.

I have a simple method that throws an exception if it gets an empty input string:

```
public SumarniVzorec( String sumarniVzorec) throws IOException
    {
        if (sumarniVzorec == "")
        {
            IOException emptyString = new IOException("The input string is empty");
            throw emptyString;
        }
```

I want to test that the exception is actually thrown if the argument is an empty string. For that, I use following code:

```
    @Test(expected=IOException.class)
    public void testEmptyString()
    {
        try
        {
            SumarniVzorec test = new SumarniVzorec( "");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {   // Error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The result is that the exception is thrown, but the test fails.
What am I missing?

Thank you, Tomas

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Remove `try-catch` block. JUnit will receive exception and handle it appropriately (consider test successful, according to your annotation). And if you supress exception, there's no way of knowing for JUnit if it was thrown.

```
@Test(expected=IOException.class)
public void testEmptyString() throws IOException {
    new SumarniVzorec( "");
}
```

Also, **dr jerry** rightfully points out that you can't compare strings with `==` operator. Use `equals` method (or `string.length == 0`)

http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm (see 'Expected Exceptions' part)

Comment: Thank you, but I tried that already and it gives an error: unhandled Exception type IOError

Comment: You still need to declare the method as `throws IOException`

Comment: @Tomas where do you get IOError from? Can you post whole error message (with stacktrace)?

Comment: @developmentalinsanity Thanks, my bad. But it wouldn't compile otherwise, so it can't really solve IOError.

Answer (score 1):

maybe sumarniVzorec.equals("") instead of sumarniVzorec == ""

Comment: Thank you, I repaired that, but it didn't solve the problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

how about :

```
@Test
public void testEmptyString()
{
    try
    {
        SumarniVzorec test = new SumarniVzorec( "");
        org.junit.Assert.fail();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {   // Error
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is :

```
public void testEmptyString()
{
    try
    {
        SumarniVzorec test = new SumarniVzorec( "");
        assertTrue(false);

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
       assertTrue(true);
    }
```