# JUnit 'AssertionError' on Expected exception even when the exception is thrown

Tags: java, unit-testing, exception, junit

I have a function which I would like to test if it throws an exception as so :

```
 @Override
    public WorkOrderTask updateWorkOrderTaskWithOutcome(String taskId, String outcome, WorkOrderTask workOrderTask) {
        Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();

        if (!outcome.equals(TaskOutcomes.CANCEL.getValue())) {
            WorkOrderType workOrder = workOrderTask.getWorkOrderPayload().getWorkOrder();
            workOrder = workflowDataService.updateWorkOrder(workOrder);
            workOrderTask.getWorkOrderPayload().setWorkOrder(workOrder);

            variables = getProcessVariables(workOrder);
        }

        try {
            workflowTaskService.completeTask(taskId, outcome, variables);
            logger.debug("Updated Task ID: {} with outcome {}", taskId, outcome);
        } catch (WorkflowException e) {
            logger.error("Updating Work Order Task ID: {} with outcome {} FAILED", taskId, outcome, e);
        }

        return workOrderTask;
    }
```

The test I wrote was this :

```
@Test(expected=WorkflowException.class)
public void testUpdateWorkOrderTaskForWorkflowException() throws Exception {
    WorkOrderTask workOrderTask = GrcWorkflowTestUtil.generateWorkOrderTask();
    WorkOrderType workOrder = workOrderTask.getWorkOrderPayload().getWorkOrder();

    doReturn(workOrder).when(workflowDataService).updateWorkOrder(workOrder);//some mock stubs to avoid calling actual service
    doThrow(new WorkflowException("test workflow exception")).when(workflowTaskService).completeTask(any(), any(), any());//forcing the exception to be thrown

    WorkOrderTask workOrderTaskRet = workOrderService.updateWorkOrderTaskWithOutcome(TestEnvironmentUtil.TASK_ID,
            TaskOutcomes.SUBMIT.getValue(), workOrderTask);

}
```

Now when I run the test I get > AssertionError: excepted exception :workflowException, even though I can see(debug) that the workflowException was thrown .

I did read this question which was kind of similar  :
[Testing for Exceptions using JUnit. Test fails even if the Exception is caught](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896614/testing-for-exceptions-using-junit-test-fails-even-if-the-exception-is-caught)

But the answer says that I have to skip the try catch block ,which is something I don't want to do.

Also, the whole point of the test is to be sure the exception is caught , I know this seems like I testing for the implementation rather then the API but I don't want to trigger the actual exception as that would warrant for calling the actual service

Comment: If your tested method does not throw the exception itself then you cannot test it this way. But your code *loggs* the exception and you can (and should) test that behavior of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to ensure that your code catches `WorkflowException` ?
But you have already this here :

```
    doThrow(new WorkflowException("test workflow exception"))
    .when(workflowTaskService).completeTask(any(), any(), any());
```

If the test execution doesn't raise an exception, it means that the risen exception in this mocking operation was caught.
So `@Test(expected=WorkflowException.class)` should not be specified.

If you want to be sure that the mocking method was performed, you can still verify that `workflowTaskService.completeTask()` was invoked. And if it was invoked, it means the exception was thrown.